# SQL self join to get count difference between records

Tags: sql, join, hana

Pardon the title as I could not think of a good title for my problem.
I have a table as below

| L_DATE | GRP | Counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20.01.2023 | A | 100 |
| 21.01.2023 | A | 150 |
| 22.01.2023 | B | 200 |
| 20.01.2023 | C | 500 |
| 21.01.2023 | C | 800 |
| 22.01.2023 | C | 1200 |

The desired output is like this

| GRP | Current Count | Last Count | Diff1 | Last2Last Count | Diff2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 150 | -150 | 100 | -100 |
| B | 200 | 0 | 200 | 0 | 200 |
| C | 1200 | 800 | 400 | 500 | 700 |

where,
Current Count is the count of latest date - 22.01.2023
Last Count is the count of previous date - 21.01.2023
Last2Last Count is the count of last to last date - 20.01.2023
Diff1 is the difference between Current Count and Last Count
Diff2 is the difference between Current Count and Last2Last Count
0 appears where there is no data for that date, for example A does not have any record for latest date 22.01.2023 so its 'Current Count' is 0. Similarly B does not have any record for 21.01.2023 or 20.01.2023 so its 'Last Count' and 'Last2Last Count' is 0.

I have tried all sorts of joins but cannot achieve the desired results. Below is my latest code, which gives me result of C and B but not A.

```
select distinct 
T1.GRP,
T1.Counts as "Current Count",
ifnull(T2.Counts,0) as "Last Count",
T1.Counts - T2.Counts as "Diff1",
ifnull(T3.Counts,0) as "Last2Last Count",
T1.Counts - T3.Counts as "Diff2"
from tbl T1
left  join tbl T2  on (T2.L_DATE = '21.01.2023' and T2.GRP = T1.GRP)
left  join tbl T3  on (T3.L_DATE = '20.01.2023' and T3.GRP = T1.GRP)
where T1.L_DATE = ('22.01.2023')
```

I tried to achieve it via GROUP_BY but did not succeed. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What is the _type_ of the `L_DATE` column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen L_DATE is of DATE data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate test data

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (L_DATE DATE, GRP VARCHAR(1), COUNTS INTEGER);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('20.1.2023', 'A', 100);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('21.1.2023', 'A', 150);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('22.1.2023', 'B', 200);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('20.1.2023', 'C', 500);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('21.1.2023', 'C', 800);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('22.1.2023', 'C', 1200);
```

Next you need to "fill the empty lines". For dates you may want to use [SERIES_GENERATE](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_CLOUD_DATABASE/c1d3f60099654ecfb3fe36ac93c121bb/c8101037ad4344768db31e68e4d30eb4.html?locale=en-US) instead, if not all dates are present in the data.

```
WITH expected_lines AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.L_DATE, b.GRP
    FROM TEST a, TEST b
)
SELECT el.L_DATE, el.GRP, ifnull(t.COUNTS, 0) AS COUNTS
FROM expected_lines el
LEFT JOIN TEST t ON el.L_DATE = t.L_DATE AND el.GRP = t.GRP
```

As you proposed, two self-joins based on this intermediate result would do the job. However, I would prefer to use window function [LAG](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_CLOUD_DATABASE/c1d3f60099654ecfb3fe36ac93c121bb/e7ef7cc478f14a408e1af27fc1a78624.html?locale=en-US) instead.

```
WITH expected_lines AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.L_DATE, b.GRP
    FROM TEST a, TEST b
)
SELECT 
    el.L_DATE, 
    el.GRP, 
    ifnull(t.COUNTS, 0) AS COUNTS,
    LAG(ifnull(t.COUNTS,0), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY el.GRP ORDER BY el.L_DATE) AS LASTCOUNT,
    LAG(ifnull(t.COUNTS,0), 2) OVER (PARTITION BY el.GRP ORDER BY el.L_DATE) AS LAST2LASTCOUNT
FROM expected_lines el
LEFT JOIN TEST t ON el.L_DATE = t.L_DATE AND el.GRP = t.GRP
```

Note that this gives you the desired result also for historical dates. You can add a WHERE condition for the current date. Also you can additionally calculate the differences:

```
WITH expected_lines AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.L_DATE, b.GRP
    FROM TEST a, TEST b
)
SELECT L_DATE, GRP, COUNTS, LASTCOUNT, COUNTS-LASTCOUNT DIFF1, LAST2LASTCOUNT, COUNTS-LAST2LASTCOUNT DIFF2
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        el.L_DATE, 
        el.GRP, 
        ifnull(t.COUNTS, 0) AS COUNTS,
        LAG(ifnull(t.COUNTS,0), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY el.GRP ORDER BY el.L_DATE) AS LASTCOUNT,
        LAG(ifnull(t.COUNTS,0), 2) OVER (PARTITION BY el.GRP ORDER BY el.L_DATE) AS LAST2LASTCOUNT
    FROM expected_lines el
    LEFT JOIN TEST t ON el.L_DATE = t.L_DATE AND el.GRP = t.GRP
)
WHERE L_DATE = '22.1.2023'
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately when I give where condition -> WHERE el.L_DATE = '22.01.2023' , I am getting null in lastcount and last2last count for all 3 records. Also can you please give the complete code in case i want to use self join?

Comment: Also, table has records A, B and C across other dates also. So I want to make the sql such that any 3 dates can be provided as inputs, latest date will be considered as current and oldest as last2last. So, I guess PARTITION BY will not work in that case.

Comment: You need to apply the `WHERE` condition as well as calculating the difference to the final dataset as a subselect. I did append this for your convenience.